# Flattening multiple tables to a single type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to model a database currently using EntityFramework's Fluent Configuration. I cannot edit or otherwise control the database schema. The entity I am trying to model has a lot of look-up tables - for example, one property (it's name) has a whole table devoted to it with a name associated with an id (which is it's language). In other words, it looks a bit like this in the database:

```
Entity
    string[] Names

Entity_Names
    string Name
    int LanguageId // 9 = English
```

However, I am trying to condense this into

```
Entity
   string Name // I only want the English name
```

Using a SQL query, this would be pretty simple - but how can I do this via Entity Framework's fluent configurations? There are a lot more of these instances as well, but this is the simplest example I could come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do manage to flatten the model this way, it's almost certainly going to be a read-only view of the data. There's no way for Entity Framework to know that a string property should be looked up in another table and replaced with an integer id.

So that leaves two options if you're okay with it being view-only. Write a database view that replaces the ids with the strings and build an entity for that view.

Or build entities that are compatible with the schema model and project the data into a dto.

The second approach is the one I'd prefer as it means you'd still have a compatible entity model if you do need to CRUD.

Comment: This is fine, as the data I am reading for is immutable. I've decided that I can use a Discriminator column for this - `Map(m=>m.Requires(x=>x.LanguageID).HasValue(9))`